# Drop down menu's in VSCode are black/blank

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

This is my first question on here, so I apologize if it's confusing or redundant. I'm doing research for one of my professors, and I'm having a really annoying problem on my Virtual Machine. I'm running Ubuntu 18.0.4 through virtual Box and VSCode's drop down menu's/right click menu's are **black**. The text is unreadable but I am able to click in the box  on whatever choice I'd be hovering over.

[When I try to click on a drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMBLA.png)

[When I right click on anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSHJn.png)

I've tried updating to the most recent version of VSCode (January 2020) and a complete uninstall + reinstall. I haven't been able to find anyone online that's had the same problem as me either. Has anyone experienced this bug before? If so, have you been able to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Same issue here, did you tried to disable 3d acceleration ?

Answer (score 4):

This should work even if you are not using the integrated terminal and menus are still immediately blacked out after opening the application:

1. Use CTRL-shift-P shortcut to open the command palette
2. Choose "Preferences: Open Settings (UI)"
3. Search for "Terminal: Explorer Kind"
4. Select "external"
5. Restart VSCode

Answer (score 1):

since other answers doesnt really looks to work, you just have to disable 3d acceleration in the vm settings.
If you have trouble running it, you should increase the ram and the num of processors.

Comment: post your suggestion as a comment, instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running Ubuntu on a VM.

The blacked-out menus seem to be caused by the terminal window.  I closed the terminal window and restarted Code and haven't had the problem since.  I guess I can live without the embedded terminal window.